# setOnclickListener(this) ERROR

Tags: java, android, android-studio

When I try to call setOnClickListener(this); 'this' gets an error. I have tried to declare it as other things but that didn't work. I am only trying to make multiple onClick events.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ImageButton button;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ImageButton one = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.img1);
    one.setOnClickListener(this);<-error

     ImageButton two = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.img1);
    one.setOnClickListener(this);<-error

    ImageButton three = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.img2);
    two.setOnClickListener(this);<-error
  }
 public OnClickListener onClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()){
            case R.id.img1:
                button.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.checkmark);
                break;
            case R.id.img2:
                button.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.checkmark);
                break;
            case R.id.img3:
                button.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.checkmark);
                break;    
          }
       }
     };
 }
```

Comment: Did you try reading the error message? What makes you think that `this` is a valid listener?

Comment: It should be `one.setOnClickListener(onClickListener)`. Same for `two`.

Comment: `this` does not implement OnClickListener

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `this`,  reference your already created `onClickListener` class member. Also you have a bug in your 2nd and 3rd imagebutton where it is not getting any clicklistener or targeting the wrong resource id, here is all the fixes

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ImageButton one = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.img1);
    one.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);

     ImageButton two = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.img2);
    two.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);

    ImageButton three = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.img3);
    three.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
ImageButton one = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.img1);
one.setOnClickListener(onClickListener );
```

Answer (score 0):

change your class declaration to :

```
        public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

        ImageButton button;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            ImageButton one = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.img1);
            one.setOnClickListener(this);<-error

             ImageButton two = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.img1);
            one.setOnClickListener(this);<-error

            ImageButton three = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.img2);
            two.setOnClickListener(this);<-error
          }

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                switch(v.getId()){
                    case R.id.img1:
                        button.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.checkmark);
                        break;
                    case R.id.img2:
                        button.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.checkmark);
                        break;
                    case R.id.img3:
                        button.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.checkmark);
                        break;    
                  }
               }

         }
```

Comment: I've just edit my answer , thank you for correct me.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener
```

just implement this on first line otherwise all thing ok.